# How can make none scrollable header and scrollable body in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to build a project, with none scrollable header and scrollable body. SliverAppbar is the choice first but if I move body than I lost the header. Also I can use Slidabele Tile. The SliverPersistentHeader is my second choice but I can use Slidabele Tile. My problem is shown below picture. The main.dart Header must not scroll and body must contains hard coded Slidable Tile. How can make none scrollable header and scrollable body in flutter?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `appBar: AppBar(...` inside of you Scaffold.
so MaterialApp->Scaffold->(AppBar and listview).

Exaple code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("This is the title"),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("This is text 1"),
            Text("This is text 2"),
            Text("This is text 3"),
            Text("This is text 4"),
            Text("This is text 5"),
            Text("This is text 6"),
            Text("This is text 7"),
            Text("This is text 8"),
            Text("This is text 9"),
            Text("This is text 10"),
            Text("This is text 11"),
            Text("This is text 12"),
            Text("This is text 13"),
            Text("This is text 14"),
            Text("This is text 15"),
            Text("This is text 15"),
            Text("This is text 15"),
            Text("This is text 15"),
            Text("This is text 15"),
            Text("This is text 15"),
            Text("This is text 15"),
            Text("This is text 15"),
            Text("This is text 15"),
            Text("This is text 15"),
            Text("This is text 15"),
            Text("This is text 15"),
            Text("This is text 15"),
            Text("This is text 15"),
            Text("This is text 15"),
            Text("This is text 15"),
            Text("This is text 15"),
            Text("This is text 15"),
            Text("This is text 15"),
            Text("This is text 15"),
            Text("This is text 15"),
            Text("This is text 15"),
            Text("This is text 15"),
            Text("This is text 15"),
            Text("This is text 15"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```